# Hide number in div if it = 0

Tags: javascript, php, html, hide

I have some problem with this code and don't know how to fix it.

```
<?$result_bandeau_new_TOP_M = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id)  from tbl_customers WHERE goods='Swimwear' and model='Bandeau'");?>
<p><span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink"><?php echo mysql_result($result_bandeau_new_TOP_S, 0);?> </a></span></p>
```

I want to hide span with numeric value = 0.

This JavaScript code is not working and I don't know why

```
$function isItANumber() {var increased = parseInt($(".fon-assort").text());

if(isNaN(increased) || increased <= 0) {$(".fon-assort").hide();
}
}
isItANumber();
```

Maybe i can do this by php, but i don't know how, so.. i try to do this by Query.

Comment: That code does not look pretty. You have a query written in the PHP-part of an HTML-page? O.o

Comment: Value of what equals 0?

Comment: Apart from code written the wrong way you have a $ sign in front of the word function

Comment: If

S (it's a size of wear) - 0 pieces (hide it)

Comment: @u_mulder

Sorry for my bad english

If S(size of wear)  equal 0 (hide it) if not equal 0, showit

Comment: @Dylan Meeus 

Yes it's php document with html and php code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery specific selectors. By using the > you are saying, every  element under the `.fon-assort` is what I want.

Then, you loop through each seperate item, get the text value as a number with parseInt, and do a typesafe check with `===` if it equals 0, if so, hide the parent `.fon-assort` element

Also, I suggest you don't use the mysql_xxxx functions, but learn mysqli or pdo and use prepared statements for your queries. the mysl_xxx queries are depricated. that means they will vanish at some point because they are obsolete, and usage is strongly advised against.

```js
$('.fon-assort > a').each(function(index,elem) {
   var $this = $(elem);
  
   if(parseInt($this.text().trim()) === 0) {
       $this.closest('.fon-assort').hide();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink">0</a></span></p>
<p><span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink">4</a></span></p>
<p><span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink">2</a></span></p>
<p><span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink">0</a></span></p>
```

Comment: The problem really should be fixed in PHP at page generation, not with JQuery hiding afterward.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of issues with the code you posted, but the change to the second line that makes the difference you want should be something like:

```
<?php 
   $count = mysql_result($result_bandeau_new_TOP_S, 0);
   if( $count != 0) {
     echo '<p><span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink">' +
           $count
           +'</a></span></p>';
   }
?>
```

And if combining with the existing first line, you don't need the

```
?>
<?php
```

In general you should stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` syntax. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.  See comparison [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I had been trying to keep it closer to the original posted, but slowly got away from that.  It was still only one extra function call, not two, and there is a memory tradeoff, but I did update the post.

Comment: @WBT
Thank you for help. God blessing you!

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should hide span using php.
so your code should look like:

```
<?php
  $result_bandeau_new_TOP_M = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id)  from tbl_customers WHERE goods='Swimwear' and model='Bandeau'");

  $data = mysql_result($result_bandeau_new_TOP_S, 0);
?>
<p>
 <?php if ($data!=0): ?>
   <span class="fon-assort">S : <a href="somelink"><?=$data;?> </a></span>
 <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. God blessing you!

Comment: Work perfect now. Thank you. God blessing you my friend!